# How to test pending purchase?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I've just updated my app to use the latest play-billing billing (2.0) release, which forces you to support pending transactions or the libraries initialization fails fast. In the release notes for this library regarding pending transactions, i see:

> Pending transactions can be tested using license testers. In addition
> to two test credit cards, license testers have access to two new test
> instruments for delayed forms of payment which automatically complete
> or cancel after a couple of minutes.

However at runtime, in the Google Play bottom sheet for a valid license tester there's no option for the pending transaction, so how do we test this out? Is this feature not yet fully implemented in google play?

I can choose only one on this 2 options :

- Test card, always approves
- Test card, always declines

What did I miss ?

Comment: Have you ever found a way to actually get the other promised payment methods to appear in the list?

Comment: @david.mihola no not yet :(